# C2664 for std::vector cast operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, casting

Specifying a cast operator that returns a vector results in error C2664.

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::wstring>& s)
{
}

class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(const std::vector<std::wstring>& s) : m_s(s)
    {
    }
    operator std::vector<std::wstring>() const
    {
        return m_s;
    }
private:
    const std::vector<std::wstring> m_s;
};

Wrapper wrapper(std::vector<std::wstring>());
foo(wrapper);
foo(static_cast<std::vector<std::wstring>>(wrapper));
```

I get:

```
error C2664: '`anonymous-namespace'::foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '`anonymous-namespace'::Wrapper (__cdecl *)(std::vector<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(void))' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
with
[
  _Ty=std::wstring
]
Reason: cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'const std::vector<_Ty>'
with
[
  _Ty=std::wstring
]
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

The same code with a wstring does work:

```
void foo(const std::wstring& s)
{
}

class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(const std::wstring& s) : m_s(s)
    {
    }
    operator std::wstring() const
    {
        return m_s;
    }
private:
    const std::wstring m_s;
};

Wrapper wrapper(std::wstring(L"test"));
foo(wrapper);
```

Is this a bug in the Visual Studio compiler or are containers something special here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) - `wrapper` is declared as a function not an object.

Specifically, it's a function that returns `Wrapper`, and takes a pointer to a function that returns `std::vector<std::wstring>` and takes no parameters.

The constructor parameter `L"test"` avoids this in your code with `wstring`, because it can't be part of a function declaration, and so the declaration is an object definition. In this particular case, the simplest fix to your code is probably to pass `0` as a constructor parameter to the vector instead of no args.

Comment: I'd say a simpler (C++11) version would be to use the new initialization syntax: `Wrapper wrapper{std::vector<std::wstring>()};`

Comment: @Agentlien: agreed. I wonder whether in C++11 mode there would be some value to a compiler warning for using parentheses in an initialization. Optional of course, since you wouldn't want to *have* to change all such initializations in existing code, but it would break the habit that leads to this error.

Comment: @Agentlien: true, but the question is tagged as "vs2010", which to the best of my knowledge (I might be wrong though) does not support uniform initialization

Comment: Steve Jessop: I think it'd be best to at least get such a recommendation when compilation fails due to Most Vexing Parse.

@AndyProwl A valid point, I already forgot that it wasn't in VS2010.

Comment: You can simply use double parentheses: ``Wrapper wrapper((std::vector<std::wstring>()));``

Comment: @ltjax: true, that's the more general C++03 fix but in this case I think it's the worst (least easy to read or write) of the three on offer.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line:

```
Wrapper wrapper(std::vector<std::wstring>());
```

into:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> v;
Wrapper wrapper(v);
```

Your original declaration of `wrapper` is parsed as the declaration of a function which returns an object of type `Wrapper` and accepts in input a function which returns an `std::vector<std::wstring>` and takes no argument.